# Terraform - Add a specific description for each group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to put a specific description of a csv file to each group I created.
On my csv, I have 2 columns: 1 for the group name and another for the description.

```
locals {
  Right_Groups   = [for x in csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_RightGroups.csv")) : x.droits_groups]
}
```

I create each group with :

```
resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group-Right" {
  for_each = toset(local.Right_Groups)

  display_name     = lower(each.value)
  security_enabled = true
  description      = each.value
}
```

With this, the description is equal to the group name.
If I set "each.value.description" to "description", it doesn't work.

The csv is like this :

```
droits_groups,description
con-inf-dev01,dev01
con-axw-rec01,rec01
```

Anyone have an idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: What does the local variable look like, i.e., what are the values?

Comment: I added on my question the content of my csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a map instead of list which you are converting to a set. This is because of the fact that sets will have the same keys and values [1]:

> each.value — The map value corresponding to this instance. (If a set was provided, this is the same as each.key).

To convert the data to a map you could try:

```
Right_Groups = {for x in csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_RightGroups.csv")) : x.droits_groups => x.description}
```

This will create the following map:

```
> local.Right_Groups
{
  "con-axw-rec01" = "rec01"
  "con-inf-dev01" = "dev01"
}
```

Then, in the resource you would do:

```
resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group-Right" {
  for_each = local.Right_Groups

  display_name     = lower(each.key)
  security_enabled = true
  description      = each.value
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object